# how to prove that $\hat \sigma^2$ is a consistent for $\sigma^2$

Tags: statistics, regression

Consider a regression model $Y_n=X_n\beta +\varepsilon$, where $X_n$ is a $n \times p_n$ matrix, and $\varepsilon=(\varepsilon_1,...,\varepsilon_n)'$ consists of independent and identically distributed variables with $E(\varepsilon_1)=0$ and $Var(\varepsilon_1)=\sigma^2$. Suppose $\hat \sigma ^2$ is the estimator of $\sigma^2$. Let

$$\hat \sigma ^2=\frac{\left\|Y_n-X_n\hat\beta\right\|^2}{n-p_n}.$$

How to prove that $\hat \sigma^2$ consistent for $\sigma^2$?

Comment: Can you assume normality of the error term $\epsilon$?

Comment: No. I cannot assume normality of $\varepsilon$

Comment: If I assume normality of the error term, how can I use the assumption to prove that $\hat \sigma^2$ is consistent for $\sigma^2$?

Comment: I've edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot assume normality then 
$\hat{e}_i = y_i - x_i'\hat{\beta} = e_i+x_i'\beta - x_i'\hat{\beta}=e_i+x_i'(\beta - \hat{\beta})$,
recall that $\hat{\beta}_n \xrightarrow{p}\beta$, thus 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n-p}||Y-X\hat{\beta}||^2 &= \frac{1}{n-p}\sum_{i=1}^n\hat{e}_i^2\\
 &= \frac{1}{n-p}(\sum_{i=1}^n e^2_i + 2\sum_{i=1}^n e_ix_i'(\beta-\hat{\beta}) + (\beta-\hat{\beta})'\sum_{i=1}^n (x_ix_i')(\beta-\hat{\beta})),
\end{align}
where the second and the third terms converge in probability to $0$ and the first term goes to $\mathbb E{e_i^2}=\sigma^2$.

[1] Such a proof can be found in Econometrics by Bruce E. Hansen. If you can assume normality of the error term, then you can use the $\chi ^2$ distribution to prove consistency which can be slightly easier.

---

If you can assume normality then the proof becomes much easier as 
$$
\mathbb{E}\hat{\sigma}^2 = \sigma^2,
$$
then the MSE of $\hat{\sigma}^2$ equals its variance, i.e., 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} MSE(\hat{\sigma}^2) &= \lim_{n\to \infty} Var(\frac{\sigma^2}{n-p} \frac{||Y-X\hat{\beta}||^2}{\sigma^2})\\
& =\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sigma^4}{(n-p)^2} Var( \frac{||Y-X\hat{\beta}||^2}{\sigma^2})\\
& = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2(n-p)\sigma^4}{(n-p)^2}\\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2\sigma^4}{(n-p)}=0.
\end{align}

Comment: I cannot assume normality. However, I can prove $\hat \sigma^2$ is unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$. In order to prove the consistency, I need to prove $\lim Var(\hat \sigma^2)=0$. I stuck here.

Comment: I cannot understand the equation. For the first step, why $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} MSE(\hat \sigma^2)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} Var (\frac{\sigma^2}{n-p} \left \| Y_n-X_n\hat \beta \right \|^2)$ ?? where does $\sigma^2$ come from?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the $\sigma^2$ in the denominator too. Anyhow, it is just a "trick" to get the $\chi^2$ distribution and then I used the fact that a variance of $\chi^2_{(n)}$ equals $2n$.. For more details on the you can see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030401/proof-that-sum-of-squares-of-error-for-simple-linear-regression-follows-chi-squa/2038778#2038778) answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But in your case, X is followed normal distribution. Does the result still work for my case? Cause in my case, X is not said to be follow normal distribution.

Comment: No. The chi distribution is a result of the normal assumption. for non normal noise, you can use the first proof. It does not assumes any parametric structure of $\epsilon$.

Comment: My supervisor told me the first proof cannot be used in my case. The condition of X in first proof is random. But for my case, X is fixed. So may I add an assumption such that X follows the normal distribution in the statement??

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether $X$ is random or not. You can use the fact that $\hat{\beta}_n \xrightarrow{p} \beta$ to prove the consistency of $\hat{\sigma}^2$.